# Azure Analysis Service After Deployment with Import From Server (Tabular) Have Duplicate Model

Tags: ssas, azure-analysis-services, analysisservices

I have deployment Azure Analysis Service from Visual Studio SSDT (2017) which I'am create new solution with Import From Server (Tabular Existing from Azure Analysis Service Model). in properties model we have input the correct model and server.

After deploy, I have duplicate model with generate character like this:

[image: Duplicate Model and Add some character]

So, I have 2 model with same table, row, measure ..
my goal is model is deployment

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database name with the format of `<project name>_<user ID>_<GUID>` is created when you have the `Workspace server` setting in your Visual Studio solution set to the Server.

It is just a temporary one, which is used when you work on your Visual Studio solution.

If you don't want it, you can use the `Integrated workspace` option.

[image]

The official documentation of this setting is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/workspace-database-ssas-tabular?view=asallproducts-allversions

> When you create a new tabular model project, you specify an Analysis Services server instance to use while authoring your project:

> **Integrated workspace** - Recommended. Utilizes Visual Studio's own internal instance. Use this setting when creating a project that will be deployed to Azure Analysis Services.

> **Workspace server** - A workspace database is created on an explicit instance, often on the same computer as Visual Studio or another computer in the same network. While you can specify an Azure Analysis Services server, it's not recommended. Using a Power BI workspace as the Workspace server is not supported.